# gradle: How do I find out the plugin that implemented a particular task?

Tags: gradle

I have a bunch of gradle plugins being used in my build. Many of these plugins, in turn, use other plugins. I want to figure out the plugin which implemented a particular task. Is there a core gradle task to find that out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no core task that will tell you which plugin is responsible for which task. You can see all tasks available by running:

`gradle tasks`

However there are a few hints in the log. If you run the build with the `--debug` switch, you can see tasks being registered after a plugin dependency has been resolved:

```
10:20:25.847 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Found artifact 'gradle-release.jar (net.researchgate:gradle-release:2.3.5)' in resolver cache: C:\g\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.researchgate\gradle-release\2.3.5\8045af5040f3efa88abbc5879fd51cf1634a2536\gradle-release-2.3.5.jar
10:20:26.041 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'tasks.release' (hidden = false)
10:20:26.076 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'tasks.createScmAdapter' (hidden = false)
10:20:26.086 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'tasks.initScmAdapter' (hidden = false)
10:20:26.086 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'tasks.checkCommitNeeded' (hidden = false)
10:20:26.087 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'tasks.checkUpdateNeeded' (hidden = false)
10:20:26.088 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'tasks.unSnapshotVersion' (hidden = false)
10:20:26.088 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'tasks.confirmReleaseVersion' (hidden = false)
10:20:26.089 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'tasks.checkSnapshotDependencies' (hidden = false)
10:20:26.091 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'tasks.runBuildTasks' (hidden = false)
10:20:26.093 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'tasks.preTagCommit' (hidden = false)
10:20:26.094 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'tasks.createReleaseTag' (hidden = false)
10:20:26.094 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'tasks.updateVersion' (hidden = false)
10:20:26.095 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'tasks.commitNewVersion' (hidden = false)
10:20:26.127 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'tasks.beforeReleaseBuild' (hidden = false)
10:20:26.128 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Project : - Registering model element 'tasks.afterReleaseBuild' (hidden = false)
```

Which will tell you tasks registered by this plugin ([gradle release](https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release)) dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably print the class name for each plugin and each task and hopefully the package will give you a hint

eg:

```
task printStuff {
    doLast {
        plugins.all { Plugin plugin ->
            println "Plugin: ${plugin.class.name}"
        }
        tasks.all { Task task ->
            println "Task: ${task.class.name} (name=${task.name})"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have temporarily added the following piece of code inside my root folder `build.gradle`:

This is for the task with name `lint`. You can adapt for any other task.

```
allprojects { project ->
    beforeEvaluate {
        tasks.whenTaskAdded {
            if (it.name == "lint") {
                println("++++++++ Task added, project: $project, class: ${it.class.name}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I just run:

```bash
$ ./gradlew -q tasks
```

and it prints out information about the `lint` task, which projects they define it and which is the implementation class name. From the class name I can usually tell which plugin has defined that task.